# Help Understanding Fields

Tags: field-theory

I came across this problem in a Linear Algebra text today:

> Let $u$ and $v$ be distinct vectors in a vector space $V$ over a field $F$. Prove that $\{u,v\}$ is linearly independent if and only if $\{u+v,u-v\}$ is linearly independent.

Working on ($\Rightarrow$), I must show that

$$c_1(u+v) + c_2(u-v) = 0 \implies c_1 = c_2 = 0 \text{, where } c_1,c_2 \in F.$$

Using linear independence of $\{u,v\}$ I arrive at the equation $c_1 + c_1 = 0$. However, if $F = \mathbb{Z}_2$ then $1 + 1 = 0$. Also, if $c_1$ and $c_2$ were "integers" then in a field of characteristic $2$ I have

$$c_1 + c_1 = \underbrace{(1 + \cdots + 1)}_{c_1 \text{ times}} + \underbrace{(1 + \cdots + 1)}_{c_1 \text{ times}} = (1 + 1) + \cdots + (1 + 1) = 0 + \cdots + 0 = 0$$

However, I'm assuming that they're integers and I'm not sure (as for example $\mathbb{R}$ is a field which isn't only integers) that $x + x = 0$ in *any* field with characteristic $2$. Can someone clarify?

Also, I see often the restriction that $F$ be of characteristic not equal to $2$. Why is that?

My knowledge of fields is very limited so any references would also be appreciated.

Thank-you.

Comment: Yes, characteristic 2 means $x+x=0$ for all $x$ in the field.

Comment: ... as $x+x = x(1+1) = x\cdot 0$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The statement you are trying to prove is, indeed, not true if the field has characteristic $2$. If $u=(1,0)$ and $v=(0,1)$ then $u$ and $v$ are linearly independent but $u+v=u-v=(1,1)$.

Comment: I have always been uneasy about statements such as *(the set) $\{ u, v \}$ is linearly independent*. This is of course because if $u$ is a nonzero vector, then $\{ u \} = \{ u, u \}$, so is this *set* independent or not? In this case, even in characteristic two, one might thus claim that  $\{ u+v, u-v \} = \{ u+ v \}$, with $u + v \ne 0$ if $u \ne v$, so the set $\{ u+ v \}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti Why is that a problem? Linear dependence is defined as $S$ is linear dependent if there exists a finite number of *distinct* vectors and scalars $a_1,\ldots,a_n$, not all zero, such that $a_1v_1 + \cdots + a_nv_n = 0$. Linear independence is then defined as not linear dependent. So linear combinations should be taken over *distinct* vectors of $S$ in which case if $u \neq 0$ $\{u,u\}$ is linearly independent.

Comment: @BryanUrízar, there are two possible definitions http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence With the definition you prefer, I *believe* one has to exert a little extra care when defining for instance a basis and dimension.

Comment: @Andreas, you raise a valid point. Perhaps I should have phrased my answer in these terms: in characteristic 2, there are examples where $u$ and $v$ are independent, but $u+v$ and $u-v$ are dependent.

Comment: @GerryMyerson, thanks. Of course I know I am being a bit finicky here, and I understood perfectly well what you meant also in the original formulation.

Comment: @AndreasCaranti I wasn't aware of that definition and I definitely see what you mean now. I'm just not sure how its possible to use such a definition when you have situations like the one you mentioned. Also, my text uses the fact that they're distinct quite often which is why it's actually stuck in my head. Might be a good idea to go back and try proving things using this alternate definition. Thanks for your post.

Comment: @BryanUrízar, you're welcome.